# Restablecer conexion con SMTPlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, try-catch

Buenas Tardes:

Tengo un programita de Python que lo que hace es leer un mensaje de Telegram y envia el mismo mensaje pero por email mediante la libreria SMPT. El problema es que por casualidad envio dos mensajes de Telegram a la vez el programa intenta enviar dos correos y me da un error. Para solucionar esto he puesto un try/exception, tal de este modo:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx")
#mas codigo...

try:
       server.sendmail(emisor, receptor, mensaje.as_string())
       print "Try"                     
except Exception:
       print "Exception"
       #pass
       sys.exc_clear()
```

El problema es que cuando se salta el error la conexion SMTP queda desconectada y no puede enviar mas mensajes de email:

> SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first

Para solucionar esto he intentado añadir al codigo lo que me dice el error, quedando de esta manera:

```
try:
       server.sendmail(emisor, receptor, mensaje.as_string())
       print "Try"                     
except Exception:
       server.connect()
       print "Exception"
       #pass
       sys.exc_clear()
```

Pero esto a su vez me devuelve un error:

> error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Estoy bastante perdido, y no se como salir de esta. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Lo que deberías evitar es el primer problema, envío de dos mail uno atrás del otro. Desconozco pero puedo imaginarme que Gmail tiene algún sistema de bloqueo anti-spam, y en estos casos te desconecta y tal vez te ponga en una "greylist" y te imponga un tiempo mínimo para volver a conectarte.

Comment: Si a priori parece lo mas simple evitar el primer problema. Ya lo habia pensado, pero lo he descartado por varios problemas. Por eso la solucion que estoy pidiendo es el de reconectar con SMTP. Gracias.

Comment: Nadie sabria aclararme este tema?Gracias.